# How can I display the input value?

Tags: javascript, dom, input, addeventlistener, display

I would like to show what I write in the input, but everytime I try the alert window shows "undefined".
This is the code.
Thanks.

```
<body>
    <input id="input"></input>
    <button id="search">search</button>
   
    <script>
        document.getElementById('search').addEventListener("click", show);
        var input = getElementById('input');
        var search = input.value;
        function show() {
          alert(search);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `getElementById('input');` should be `document.getElementById('input');` You assign to  *search* once, before any value has been entered and never update it. Try `alert(input.value)`.

Comment: please format the code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to use `document.getElementById` instead of just `getElementById`.
Then you need to put `var search = input.value` inside the `show` function so that it gets the current value each time you want to show it, and not just the initial one.

```js
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener("click", show);
var input = document.getElementById('input');

function show() {
  var search = input.value;
  alert(search);
}
```

```html
<input id="input"></input>
<button id="search">search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must bring `var search` into `show` function declaration in order to get new value of search box every time the event occurs.

```
function show(){
  var search = input.value;
  alert(search);
}
```